# How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value)?

Tags: sql

My table

```
ODR_NBR |   Snbr12      |   appot_nbr      | Creatins_ts
1       |   4001        |   2458           | 11/24/2015 4:38:00 PM
1       |   4001        |   2458           | 11/22/2015 4:50:00 PM
2       |   4005        |   3598           | 11/27/2015 4:38:00 PM
2       |   4005        |   3598           | 11/24/2015 4:20:00 PM
```

My table after sql

```
ODR_NBR |   Snbr12      | Creatins_ts
1       |   4001        |  11/24/2015 4:38:00 PM
2       |   4005        |  11/27/2015 4:38:00 PM
```

Comment: You will need to `group by ODR_NBR` and `select Max(Snbr1)`. What does your query look like so far?

Comment: Fagua you may also want to mention which SQL Engine you are using. It always helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the result you want:

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ODR_NBR int ,  Snbr12     int ,  appot_nbr    int   ,Creatins_ts datetime)

 INSERT INTO table1
 VALUES
    (1       ,  4001        ,  2458           ,'11/24/2015 4:38:00 PM'),
    (1       ,  4001        ,  2458           ,'11/22/2015 4:50:00 PM'),
    (2       ,  4005        ,  3598           ,'11/27/2015 4:38:00 PM'),
    (2       ,  4005        ,  3598           ,'11/24/2015 4:20:00 PM')
```

Query:

```
    SELECT ODR_NBR ,  Snbr12  ,  MAX(Creatins_ts) AS Creatins_ts 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY ODR_NBR ,  Snbr12
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
SELECT t1.ODR_NBR, t1.Snbr12, t1.Creatins_ts 
FROM mytable t1 JOIN mytable t2 
    ON t1.ODR_NBR=t2.ODR_NBR
WHERE t1.Creatins_ts > t2.Creatins_ts
```